# Cannot generate PDF: This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator

Tags: .net, pdf

I am running MVC(.Net with C#) site on windows dedicated server 2012 R2.

Actually I am generating PDF from HTML using "NReco.PdfGenerator.dll" file. Its working fine in my local pc but when I try to generating same from dedicated server then its give me error as below:-
"Cannot generate PDF: This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator"

Comment: So... contact your system administrator?

Comment: NReco PdfGenerator is a wrapper for wkhtmltopdf tool (it is executed with System.Diagnostics.Process). Ensure that your ASP.NET application has enough permissions to do that.